# Height of a trie (number of levels)

Tags: java, trie, levels

I have a *trie* where each node is an object `TrieNode` like this:

```
public char content; 
public double count;
public LinkedList<TrieNode> childList;
```

I had to count the height of the trie (root had level = 0).

So this is what I've done:

```
int levels = getLevels(getRoot());
System.out.println("levels: " + levels);

public int getLevels(TrieNode node) {
    int lev = 0;
    if(node != null) {
        TrieNode current = node;  
        for(TrieNode child : node.childList) {
            lev += getLevels(child);
        }      
    }   
    return lev;
}
```

But it returns always 0. Why?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add 1 when you descend to children, otherwise nothing gives `lev` a non-zero value.

Note that you're not calculating [the height of the trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Terminologies_used_in_Trees) in this code, you're summing the lengths of the paths. You need to find the *maximum* path length:

```
int lev = 1;
for (TrieNode child : node.childList) {
  lev = Math.max(lev, 1 + getLevels(child));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you were fast.